# sort a vector that holds objects by a member string in that class

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to sort this class but for some reason I cannot get it to work. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class CLog
{
public:
    string GetName()
    {
        return m_sName;
    }

    void SetName(string sName)
    {
        m_sName = sName;
    }
private:
    string m_sName = "";
};

bool sortByName(const CLog &lhs, const CLog &rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetName() < rhs.GetName();
}

int main()
{
    vector<CLog> lsLog;

    CLog oLog1;
    oLog1.SetName("b");
    lsLog.push_back(oLog1);

    CLog oLog2;
    oLog2.SetName("c");
    lsLog.push_back(oLog2);

    CLog oLog3;
    oLog3.SetName("a");
    lsLog.push_back(oLog3);


    sort(lsLog.begin(),
     lsLog.end(),
     sortByName
     );

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me these errors

25|error: passing ‘const CLog’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string CLog::GetName()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|

25|error: passing ‘const CLog’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string CLog::GetName()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|

Comment: `#include <algorithm>`, and make `getName` `const`.

Comment: @BoBTFish: Please do not write answers in the comment section. We cannot peer review them properly.

Comment: @Lightness It's questionable if that question deserves an answer at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Well, it is an MCVE, at least. The "M" part could be stronger, but still. A very rare thing to see these days.

Comment: i tried to mock up a simple test because it is way too much code but in the original I did have #include <algorithm>.  The real error is passing ‘const CLog’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string CLog::GetName()’ discards qualifiers

Comment: @flashc5 Actually your vector holds objects, not classes.

Comment: I updated it to const but it still errors.  I dont get what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-`const` member function:

```
string GetName()
{
    return m_sName;
}
```

That means it's deemed a function that "modifies" the object. We can see from the code that actually you didn't, but `const`-correctness doesn't care about that. You simply can't call such a function on a `const CLog`, or via a `const CLog&`, or via a `const CLog*`.

This is also a non-`const` member function, though it returns a `const string`:

```
const string GetName()
{
    return m_sName;
}
```

To make the member function itself `const`, you put the keyword at the end, like this:

```
string GetName() const
{
    return m_sName;
}
```

Now you can call the function on a `const` object, and if you try to write code inside the function that modifies the object, the compiler won't let you.

This *should* be explained in your C++ book. If it's not, get [a better one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)!

Comment: @flashc5: No problem! Also read https://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html